# How to use Axios API client generated by OpenAPITools code generator?

Tags: typescript, axios

I am using Swagger/OpenAPI Codegen to generate an API client for the Fetch client in my Vue app and want to use Axios instead. I started by using the [OpenAPITools](https://github.com/OpenAPITools) typescript-axios code generator:

```
java -jar .\openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json -g typescript-axios -o app\api
```

I then tried to assign the typed response in to a local variable of the same type:

```
@Component
export default class Themes extends Vue {
  private themesApi!: ThemesApi;
  private themes: Theme[];

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.themes = [];
  }

  private async mounted() {
    const apiConfig: Configuration = {
      basePath: config.API_URL,
    };

    this.themesApi = new ThemesApi(apiConfig);
  }

  private async getThemes() {
    this.themes = await this.themesApi.getThemes();
  }
}
```

However, this raised the following TypeScript error:

```
> 139:5 Type 'AxiosResponse<Theme[]>' is missing the following
> properties from type 'Theme[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28
> more.
>     137 | 
>     138 |   private async getThemes() {
>   > 139 |     this.themes = await this.themesApi.getThemes();
>         |     ^
```

The local variable is of the same type:
[image: Screenshot showing local variable has the same type.]

So why is it raising this error?

Comment: Did you get codegeneration working from Swagger/OpenAPI to Axios with Vue? Would be great if you can publish that.

Comment: found this - https://github.com/johndpope/openapi-typescript-client-api-generator/

Comment: @TomasBjerre I switched to use NSwag / NSwag Studio instead, works better for me. https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag

Comment: ok nice, I also solved it: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pom-dependency-analyzer-web-frontend/blob/master/package.json#L11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the types for Axios, specifically `AxiosResponse`: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L70

You'll see that it accepts a generic, in your case `Theme`, which will be accessible under the `data` property. So you'll need to get your value out using something like the following:

```
private async getThemes() {
  const response = await this.themesApi.getThemes();
  this.themes = response.data;
}
```